# Identificar o quantidade e valor dos argumentos recebidos em um script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Como identificar a quantidade de argumentos que recebi em um script em Bash? Como eu posso obter os valores passados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber a quantidade de argumentos que o script recebeu, use a [variável `$#`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#CLACOUNTREF). Por exemplo, se eu tenho esse script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $#
```

Assumindo que o script está no arquivo `script.sh`, se eu chamá-lo assim:

```
./script.sh a b c
```

O resultado será `3`, pois foram passados 3 argumentos (`a`, `b` e `c`).

Você pode usá-la inclusive para testar a quantidade de argumentos. Ex:

```
# se quantidade de argumentos for diferente de 3, mostra mensagem
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Só podem ter 3 argumentos"
fi
```

---

Para obter os valores do argumentos, você pode usar as variáveis `$1`, `$2`, etc:

```
# imprime o primeiro argumento
echo $1
# imprime o segundo argumento
echo $2
# imprime o terceiro argumento
echo $3
```

Caso algum dos argumentos não exista (por exemplo, você tentou acessar `$3` quando o script só recebeu 2 argumentos), o valor da respectiva variável `$n` será vazio (e o respectivo `echo` imprimirá uma linha em branco).

---

Você também pode fazer um *loop* pelos argumentos (sem precisar saber a quantidade exata), usando a [variável `$@`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF2):

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Exemplos:

```
./script.sh a b c
```

Saída:

```
a
b
c
```

---

```
./script.sh a b 'c d'
```

Saída:

```
a
b
c d
```

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que você tenha um script chamado status.sh que conte as palavras em um arquivo. Se você quiser usar esse script em muitos arquivos, é melhor passar o nome do arquivo como um argumento para que o mesmo script possa ser usado para todos os arquivos que serão processados.

entao:

```
sh status.sh listamusica
```

Os argumentos são acessados ​​dentro de um script usando as variáveis $ 1 , $ 2 , $ 3 e assim por diante. A variável $ 1 refere-se ao primeiro argumento, $ 2 ao segundo argumento e $ 3 ao terceiro argumento. Isto é ilustrado no exemplo seguinte:

```
FILE1 = $ 1 
wc $ FILE1
```

Aqui está um exemplo de como chamar esse script com argumentos da linha de comando:

```
sh status.sh listamusica1 lista de listamusica2 listamusica3
```

Se um argumento tiver espaços, coloque-o entre aspas simples. Por exemplo:

```
sh status.sh 'lista de musicas 1' 'lista de musicas 2' 'lista de musicas 3'
```

voce pode continuar a ver mais detalhes em:
https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571

Comment: `script.sh: 2: script.sh: FILE1: not found` deu problema, acho que por causa do espaço.